# Why won't it rename the file? Powershell

Tags: powershell

Can someone tell me why this script won't work?

```
Get-ChildItem "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage" -Filter *.EDIPROD | `
Foreach-Object{
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName

    #filter and save content to a new file 
    $content | Where-Object {$_ -match 'T042456'} | Rename-Item `
                                                         ($_.BaseName+'_834.txt')
```

I found this syntax from another question on here and changed the environment variables.

For some reason it won't change the name of the file. The filename is

```
'AIDOCCAI.D051414.T042456.MO.EDIPROD'
```

Help much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to TheMadTechnician I was able to get some working stuff. Great stuff actually. Figure I should share with the world!

```
#Call Bluezone to do file transfer
#start-process "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Projects\Automation\OpenBZ.bat"
#Variable Declarations
$a = Get-Date
$b = $a.ToString('MMddyy')
$source = "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\"
$dest = "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\orig"
#Find all the files that have EDIPROD extension and proceed to process them
#First copy the original file to the orig folder before any manipulation takes place
Copy-item $source\*.EDIPROD $dest
# Now we must rename the items that are in the table
Switch(GCI \\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\*.EDIPROD){
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1) -match "834*"}{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName+'_834.txt'}}
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1) -match "820*"}{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName+'_820.txt'}}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just rename the file?

Comment: I'm trying to look at the files that have a suffix of .EDIPROD, of those files the ones that match the criteria need to be renamed with a suffix of 834 and a filename type of .txt

Comment: Did you checked my answer. did it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-ChildItem's `-Filter` has issues, I really hesitate to use it in general. If it were up to me I'd do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage" |
    ?{$_.Extension -match ".EDIPROD" -and $_.name -match "T042456"}|
    %{$_.MoveTo($_.FullName+"_834.txt")}
```

Well, I would put it all on one line, but you can line break after the pipe and it does make it a little easier to read, so there you have it. I'm rambling, sorry.

**Edit:** Wow, I didn't even address what was wrong with your script. Sorry, kind of distracted at the end of my work day here. So, why doesn't your script work? Here's why:

You pull a file and folder listing for the chosen path. That's great, it should work, more or less, I have almost no faith in the `-Filter` capabilities of the file system provider, but anyway, moving on!

You take that list and run it through a ForEach loop processing each file that matches your filter as such:

1. You read the contents of the file, and store them in the variable $content
2. You run the contents of the file, line by line, there a Where filter looking for the text "T042456"
3. For each line that matches that text you attempt to rename something to that line's basename plus _834.txt (the line of text is a string, it doesn't have a basename property, and it's not an object that can be renamed, so this is going to fail)

So, that's where the issue is. You're pulling the contents of the file, and parsing that line by line trying to match the text instead of matching against the file name. If you removed Everything after the first pipe up to the Where statement, and then for your rename-item put `-newname` before your desired name, and change the `( )` to `{ }` that goes around the new name, and you would be set. Your code would work. So, your code, modified as I said, would look like:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage" -Filter *.EDIPROD | 
    Where-Object {$_ -match 'T042456'} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName+'_834.txt'}
```

Though I have a feeling you want $*.Name and not $*.BaseName. Using $_.BaseName will leave you with (to use your example file name):

```
'AIDOCCAI.D051414.T042456.MO_834.txt`
```

**Edit2:** Really that's a whole different question, how to match multiple criteria, but the question is here, I'm here, why not just get it done?

So, you have multiple criteria for matching the file names. That really doesn't affect your loop to be honest, what it does affect is the Where statement. If you have multiple options what you probably want is a RegEx match. Totally doable! I'm only going to address the Where statement (`?{ }`) here, this won't change anything else in the script.

We leave the extension part, but we're going to need to modify the file name part. With RegEx you can match against alternative text by putting it in parenthesis and splitting up the various options with a pipe character. So it would look something like this:

"(T042456|T195917|T048585)"

Now we can incorporate that into the rest of the Where statement and it looks like this:

```
?{$_.Extension -match ".EDIPROD" -and $_.name -match "(T042456|T195917|T048585)"}
```

or in your script:

```
Where-Object {$_ -match "(T042456|T195917|T048585)"}
```

**Edit3:** Hm, need the first line for the qualifier. That complicates things a bit. Ok, so what I'm thinking is to get our directory listing, get the first line of each file with the desired extension, make an object that has two properties, the first property is the fileinfo object for the file, and the other property will be the first line of the file. Wait, I think we can do better. Switch (GCI *.EDIPROD){(get-content|select -first 1) -match 820}{Rename 820};{blah blah -match 834}{rename 834}}. Yeah, that should work. Ok, actual script, not theoretical gibberish script time. This way if you have other things to look for you can just add lines for them.

```
Switch(GCI \\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\*.EDIPROD){
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1).substring(177) -match "^834"}{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {"834Dailyin$b"};Continue}
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1).substring(177) -match "^820"}{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName+'_820.txt'};Continue}
}
```

Again, if you want the EDIPROD part to remain in the file name change `$_.BaseName` to `$_.Name`. Switch is pretty awesome if you're trying to match against different things and perform different actions depending on what the results are. If you aren't familiar with it you may want to go flex your google muscles and check it out.

Hm, alternatively we could have gotten the first line inside the Where filter, run a regex match against that, and renamed the file based on the regex match.

```
GCI \\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\*.EDIPROD | ?{(GC $_ | Select -First 1) -match "(820|834)"}|Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name+"_"+$Matches[1]+".txt"}
```

Then you just have to update the Where statement to include anything you're trying to match against. That's kind of sexy, though not as versatile as the switch. But for just simple search and rename it works fine.

Comment: another great answer man thanks for addressing what was wrong with my script. The only way one can learn! Much appreciated!

Comment: there are other criteria to match in the same directory. For example we are matching the filename on "T042456", but some of the files will have "T195917", others "T048585". What kind of loop would you recommend here? I know there's several that powershell offers, but ForEach Object seems like it's going inside...deep inside my files...

Comment: Ok, appended the answer to help you out with matching multiple file names. You may want to take a little time and read up on [Regular Expressions](www.regular-expressions.info) also called RegEx for short.

Comment: yea I actually was thinking about using RegEx. It turns out matching the name isn't going to work...I need to match '834' or '820' in the first line. Just found this out after i asked you. Thanks for your time tho man. Huge help

Comment: check this out `$Files=Get-ChildItem "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage" |?{$_.Extension -match ".EDIPROD"}
Foreach-Object{
  $content=$Files| SELECT -First 1
  Where-Object {$content -match '834'}|out-file "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\834DailyIn.txt"
 
 }` won't work?

Comment: Updated answer, again.

Comment: man, you're amazing at this stuff. I wish I could give you more rep. But at this point I think you enjoy helping me...as you say "first thing we want to do". Regardless, you are the man. Lot's of good coming out of Washington these days!! Thanks again

Comment: it worked, but when i had the 820 match first, it made all the files in the group 820, when I did 834 first, it only matched the two 834s and then the 820 matched the other two. Which is accurate. I'm wondering how it would react in a situation with a hundred files.

Comment: So instead of {$_.BaseName+'_834.txt'} I want to just call it 834Dailyin+$b (as date)... What is the syntax? I have tried multiple ways...

Comment: When you are using -match you do not need the `*` after 820 or 834. I don't know why it would react like that for file order. It matches each file separately so that just seems odd. As for the 834 rename, if you have multiple files and try to name them the same you're going to have issues. Will there only ever be 1 834 file a day?

Comment: thats correct 1 834 file a day, the * wasn't a LIKE reference it was because the value I want to match is ST*834* - it's in HL7 format so technically it's one long string,and I'm afraid that there may be a scenario where 820 and 834 are in the same file...it's healthcare information so a SSN or a date may be in there as well. The only other thing I know is that the number I'm lookign for is at column 178 in the file.

Comment: "the number I'm lookign for is at column 178 in the file" that's good info really. Now we can do a `.SubString(177)` (because things start at 0 not 1) and in the match start it with a `^` which means that the match has to be the very start if the string. I updated, and fixed the 834 file name. Also added `;Continue` so once it finds a match it renames that file and immediately skips to the next file.

Comment: ah ok so switch is acting as a CASE statement. It's acting strangely. I have 5 files in my folder, plus an "orig" subdirectory where I push off the original files so I can copy back and keep testing. It looked at the first file in the folder, renamed it, second file is an 834 and it didn't touch it, nor did it touch the 3 820s..hmm.... I got this error `Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Comment: That's probably because you already have an 834Dailyin051614 file in existence.

Comment: well the actual date that needs to be appended to the end is in the filename...I was just using the variable cause I wasn't sure how to parse the filename. hmm..

Comment: regex on the part `D051414` ... perhaps something like `^/D\d{6}` ?

Comment: {$_ | ?{$_.Name -match "^.+?\.D(\d{6}).*"} | Rename-Item -NewName {"834Dailyin$($Matches[1])"}}

Comment: answer my new question for reps

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this way

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*T042456*" -Recurse | % {Rename-Item $_ "$_ _834.txt"}
```

Comment: This will leave him a file named something like `AIDOCCAI.D051414.T042456.MO.BaseName_834.txt` if you want to specify the BaseName property of the object you need to process the property before passing it to the string like `"$($_.BaseName)_834.txt"`. On the other hand I'm pretty sure PowerShell will convert the object to just the name of the file by default so you could skip the whole .BaseName bit off in general and just do "$__834.txt". Also, The BaseName will remove .EDIPROD and I don't think that's the OP's intention.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, that's good to know, Thanks. I was not sure and so given a different solution.

Comment: @Rahul I think TheMadTechnician is right, I'm going to accept his answer, but you were definitely close. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Hituptony, that's alright. After all this is a community and best answer should be accepted always.